# Is there something like a “Windows Sandbox software Wrapper”?

Tags: windows, sandbox

I am facing the following problematic: I want people to send me softwares they develop, then I want to share them to other people, in sandboxed mode, that is to say with no need to have a sandbox software...

For example, you have softwares that can manage archives, and you have auto-extracted archives.

I'd like to know if this kind of software exists: you just give it the software you want to wrap, and it gives you a sandboxed type of this soft... Then you can share it to anybody with trust that it won't harm their computer.

Do anyone know about that on the Windows OS?

**EDIT:** Solution found, but I am still looking for one that would be free.

Comment: This is offtopic here. Also, cross-posting is not approved behaviour - please try to avoid doing that. If a question is off-topic, the mods will try to identify the correct site and migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me one solution in my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843584/is-there-something-like-a-windows-sandbox-software-wrapper/7844924#7844924) on stackoverflow. If someone knows about this kind of solution as freeware or under opensource licence, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a virtual Machine (VMWare for example and creating an "Appliance") where you put the software in. This is not meeting "no need to have a sandbox software" however.

Comment: If it was just for me that would be no problem, but I want to make it easy for other users, but someone gave me a correct answer on Stackoverflow